# How to let KDevelop format source code in a "tpp" file in a way same as in a "cpp" file?

Tags: c++, include, inline, formatter, kdevelop

I'm using KDevelop 5.2, and have source files of three kinds: hpp/cpp/tpp.
Because there are many inline functions crossing invokes each other, I have to put inline codes into few of separate files with "tpp" suffix and can be included freely by other source files.

I found that the source formatter of KDevelop can not correctly/perfectly format the source code in a "tpp" file.
I had been looking through everywhere in Settings of Kdevelop, but I found no relevant option.
Is there a way, in it I can let KDevelop treat "tpp" files samely as it treat "cpp" files?

Thanks to @arrowd , my tpp files has been able to be formated as expecting, at least with simple codes.
There are still some codes can NOT be auto-formated correctly, mainly are those functions with "noexcept" qualifier.
Any hint?

Comment: Try mapping `.tpp` extension to `text/x-c++src` MIME type. If you are using Plasma, you can do it in System Settings window.

Comment: @arrowd thank you very much. I solved this problem by using your method, and it have been working for a few of months, but now it failed again. Even though I added a *.tpp extension into text/x-c++src MIME type in System Settings. sorry, I'm not very familiar with Kubuntu and Plasma.

Comment: Furthermore the "*.hpp" can not be formatted as before also!